# How to define a Flow virtual layout which vertically stacks and horizontally aligns its referenced views?

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I have defined a `ConstraintLayout` which contains a `Flow` virtual layout which tightly wraps and vertically stacks three views, as follows:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/flow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1,view2,view3"
        app:flow_horizontalAlign="start"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_maxElementsWrap="1"
        app:flow_verticalAlign="top"
        app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
        app:flow_verticalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Despite the `flow_horizontalAlign` value of `start`, this renders the views as horizontally centred, as follows:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can start/left align the referenced views instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `app:flow_horizontalBias="0"` to your Flow widget will align the views to `start`.

You can also set `android:orientation="vertical"` for the Flow widget, use the default mode `none` in the `app:flow_wrapMode` and then `flow_horizontalAlign="start"` should work as expected.

Comment: Perfect. Both techniques work. Thanks for that 

Comment: If anyone wants to see the latter of the two suggested solutions in action, check out [this](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/ConstraintLayoutExperiments/tree/master/app1) example application and [this](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/ConstraintLayoutExperiments/blob/master/app1/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) layout file in particular.

Comment: Don't forget to keep app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed" for this solution to work.